# input[type=range] error when value's updated

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a problem with a range input.
I use it as a time tracker for an audio tag, and it doesn't reacts as I want.

The value is correctly updated with the onTimeUpdate listener, but the slider thumb doesn't moves.

```
function onTimeUpdate() {
     var seeker = document.querySelector('#duration');
     var currentTime = Math.floor(player.currentTime);
     seeker.setAttribute("value", currentTime);
}
```

[image: Chrome rendering]

Is it a normal behaviour ? I can't find anything about it.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT :** "setAttribute" just sets the value of the range input. *element.value* sets the value AND the position of the cursor to a new value. Thanks to Passerby for the answer !

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Can you reproduce the issue somewhere like a js fiddler?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but try to use `.value=currentTime` instead, that seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/fep57mav/

Comment: @Passerby : Thanks a lot, it worked ! That's a little weird, but well, it's working now :)

Comment: this is to do with properties vs attributes - the `value` *property* of the DOM element is what you're trying to change, and it gets its *initial* value from the `value` *attribute* of the HTML element. But dynamically updating the *attribute* does not change the *property*. This is a constant source of confusion - check out this question and its answers for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr